# Holding a http request while an async processing is being executed

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

We have an API that works as a façade, encapsulating a call to a internal service. We're planning to change the interaction between the façade and the internal service because we're modifying the internal service to use queues, making it more resilient and elastic. We can't change the way clients use the API now, that's why we'd like to keep the blocking call between the client and the façade.

The service would expose a web method to receive the request, posting a message to a queue and returning the call as soon as possible to the façade. When the processing is done, the service would call an internal web method of the façade, releasing the first call (client to the façade).

[image: Call diagram]

The façade is built using Spring Boot and MVC. The question is: how we can "hold" the client's http request, waiting the signal from the service to return data to the client? We've considered the following approaches:

- When the API is first called, it generates an unique identifier and send it to the internal service. Then, the web method in the façade would polling (check and sleep) a singleton object (maybe a ConcurrentHashMap) looking for the object associated with the unique identifier. When the internal service signals the façade, it put the results in the singleton object, so the web method can return the information to the client.
- Using a similar approach described above with Akka actors

We're concerned about the scalability and availability of this solution (we know that holding the client http request is not good, but we have to live with that for a while).

Does anybody here had to do something similar? What was the approach used? Is there some framework (Java) that can be used?

Comment: I think spring webflux should fulfill the requirement.https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html

Comment: Did u try spring websockets ? https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/

Comment: Just use regular Spring MVC with an async executor. That will handle all of that for you. You don't need the `request` what you need is to hold on to the `response`. This is what the async processing in the servlet 3.x api is for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many technology can be used to solve your problem like : spring mvc and spring webflux

- In spring MVC, i already used DeferredResult, ResponseBodyEmitter and SseEmitter to handle asynch request and push the result back to client.

https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-async